# Is this sharper than the Resharper Robots?

Tags: c#, resharper, null-check

Resharper changed (with my approval, of course) this:

```
private static Subdepartment GetSubdepartmentForXMLElement(XElement subdept)
{
    return new Subdepartment
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(subdept.Element("Id")),
        AccountId = Convert.ToDouble(subdept.Element("AccountId ")),
        Name = subdept.Element("Name")
    };
}
```

...into this:

```
private static Subdepartment GetSubdepartmentForXMLElement(XElement subdept)
{
    var xElement = subdept.Element("Id");
    if (xElement != null)
    {
        var element = subdept.Element("AccountId");
        if (element != null)
        {
            var el = subdept.Element("Name");
            if (el != null)
            {
                return new Subdepartment
                           {
                               Id = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Value),
                               AccountId = Convert.ToDouble(element.Value),
                               Name = el.Value
                           };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...to which I had to add:

```
return null;
```

...after the penultimate curly brace, to allow it to compile.

I love R#, but the code above looks 9X uglier than a bag of butts to me; wouldn't this have been a better sharperization:

```
private static Subdepartment GetSubdepartmentForXMLElement(XElement subdept)
{
    var IdElement = subdept.Element("Id");
    var AccountIdElement = subdept.Element("AccountId");
    var NameElement = subdept.Element("Name");
    if ((IdElement != null) && (AccountIdElement != null) && (NameElement != null))
    {
        return new Subdepartment
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(IdElement.Value),
            AccountId = Convert.ToDouble(AccountIdElement.Value),
            Name = NameElement.Value
        };
    }
    return null;
}
```

?

### UPDATE

I actually prefer this "style" for some reason:

```
var IdElement = itemGroup.Element("Id");
var item_group_idElement = itemGroup.Element("item_group_id");
var nameElement = itemGroup.Element("name");
if ((null == IdElement) || (null == item_group_idElement) || (null == nameElement)) return null;
return new ItemGroup
{
    Id = Convert.ToInt32(itemGroup.Element("Id").Value),
    item_group_id = itemGroup.Element("item_group_id").Value,
    name = itemGroup.Element("name").Value
};
```

Comment: What happens when `subdept` is null? `NullReferenceException`

Comment: So why didn't super-finicky R# account for that, I wonder? Or maybe super-cautious (not a bad thing), I should ask.

Comment: Who knows, it should. It looks like you have custom settings either on your machine, or for the solution / project. It should complain about the names of your local method variables as well (should be `camelCase`, not `PascalCase`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
private static Subdepartment GetSubdepartmentForXMLElement(XElement subdept)
{
    return new Subdepartment
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Value),
        AccountId = Convert.ToDouble(element.Value),
        Name = el.Value
    };
}
```

... does not even compile. `xElement`, `element`, and `el` are not declared.

However, resharper should not complain about this:

```
private static Subdepartment GetSubdepartmentForXmlElement(XElement subdept)
{
    if (subdept == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("subdept");

    var idElement = subdept.Element("Id");
    var accountIdElement = subdept.Element("AccountId");
    var nameElement = subdept.Element("Name");

    if (idElement != null && accountIdElement != null && nameElement != null)
    {
        return new Subdepartment
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(idElement.Value),
            AccountId = Convert.ToDouble(accountIdElement.Value),
            Name = nameElement.Value
        };
    }
    return null;
}
```

Resharper code corrections only apply to one issue at a time, which is why you ended up with the nested mess in the OP. If you write code carefully from the beginning, you will need to do less of these one-issue fixes.

Personally I prefer to reduce nesting, and would like this just a little better:

```
private static Subdepartment GetSubdepartmentForXmlElement(XElement subdept)
{
    if (subdept == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("subdept");

    var idElement = subdept.Element("Id");
    var accountIdElement = subdept.Element("AccountId");
    var nameElement = subdept.Element("Name");

    if (idElement == null || accountIdElement == null || nameElement == null)
        return null;

    return new Subdepartment
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(idElement.Value),
        AccountId = Convert.ToDouble(accountIdElement.Value),
        Name = nameElement.Value
    };
}
```

ReSharper won't complain about this either.